# Print first column and email with awk or sed

Tags: linux, bash, awk, spam, mail-server

How can I use AWK in the following situation?

Example input:

```
17  mary@mysite.co.uk
9   Limited <office@domain.com>
8  "Fishing Forum" <dra.78@gmail.com>
```

Desired output:

```
17  mary@mysite.co.uk
9   office@domain.com
8   dra.78@gmail.com
```

I want print $1 with email addresses from each line.

Comment: Is the email address always the last field?

Answer (score 2):

In order to deal with all possible Email options (see tripleee comment), you need to match an Email with regexp:

```
gawk --re-interval '{match($0,/[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/);print $1 " " substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

The regexp it taken from here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html. You should test it to verify that it covers all legal Emails.

Comment: If you're using the one from regular-expressions.info, I think it's firmly established that it doesn't.

Comment: +1 for the solution but use character classes [[:alpha:]] instead of explicit ranges such as [A-Za-z] as the latter don't match all letters in all locales: `/[[:alnum:]._%+-]+@[[:alnum:].-]+\.[[:alpha:]]{2,4}/`. Note that I changes [A-Z] to [[:alpha:]] instead of [[:upper:]] as [A-Z] is obviously wrong. I suspect there other problems with that RE too but it's probably good enough.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is really as simple as you show, you can use awk `sub()` function to get ride of what you don't want, i.e.

```
 awk '{
      # inside the implied awk process-all-lines-of-input-loop
      email=$0
      if (email ~ /<\.*>/) {
        sub(/^.*</,"", email)
        sub(/>.*$/,"", email)
      } 
      else { email=$2 }
      printf("%s\t%s\n", $1, email)
      }' mailFile > newMailFile

cat newMailFile
17      17  mary@mysite.co.uk
9       office@domain.com
8       dra.78@gmail.com
```

Note that we've copied the complete line (`$0`), into the variable `email`, and then removed all chars starting at the left, until the first `<` char, then removed anything at the end of the `email` variable starting with the closing `>` char. Note that email addresses can be rather complicated to parse for the corner cases, so it's possible that this technique may miss some cases, but given it's simplicity, it should be good enough.

Also, if you're not used to awk and shell programming, note that you can't overwrite your input file with the same output filename" DON'T attempt something like `awk '....' file > file`. It will essentially wipe out  `file`.

The printf is a fancy way to print your data, the `\t` gives you a tab char in between the 2 fields.
You could also do it more simply with `print $1 "\t" email`.

IHTH.

Comment: In the real world, you might also encounter the legacy format `address@example.com (Firstname Lastname)`.

Comment: @tripleee : good point, I've updated my code to account for the very possible scenario. Thanks for the 2nd-set-of-eyes. Good luck to all!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat stack 
17  mary@mysite.co.uk
9   Limited <office@domain.com>
8  "Fishing Forum" <dra.78@gmail.com>

$ cat stack | awk '{ print $1" "$NF }' | sed 's/<//g; s/>//g'
17 mary@mysite.co.uk
9 office@domain.com
8 dra.78@gmail.com
```

If you want a `tab` between first column of output, use like following:

```
$ cat stack | awk '{ print $1"\t"$NF }' | sed 's/<//g; s/>//g'
17  mary@mysite.co.uk
9   office@domain.com
8   dra.78@gmail.com
```

If you only need email address:

```
$ cat stack | awk '{ print $NF }' | sed 's/<//g; s/>//g'
mary@mysite.co.uk
office@domain.com
dra.78@gmail.com
```

**FYI:** `NF` gives you the total number of fields in a line

Comment: You don't need to pipe awk into sed: `awk '{gsub(/[<>]/, "", $NF); print $1, $NF}'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use "sed" for that

```
$ ./test.sh | sed -r -e 's/<//g' -e 's/>//g' -e 's/^([0-9]+).* (.+)$/\1 \2/'
17 mary@mysite.co.uk
9 office@domain.com
8 dra.78@gmail.com
```